# Как настроить proxy для webview?

Tags: android, webview, proxy

В `doInBackground` `AsyncTask'а` делаю следующее:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "ХХХ.ХХХ.ХХХ.ХХХ");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "ХХХ");
doc = Jsoup.connect(myURL).get();

title = doc.outerHtml();
```

Затем в `onPostExecute AsyncTask'а` делаю следующее:

```
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, result, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Все работает, но как только из самого `WebView` переходишь по ссылкам, `proxy` уже не работает. Как добиться, чтобы `WebView` так же работал через настройки `proxy` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Гугл](https://www.google.com.) - [android webview proxy](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=uk#safe=off&hl=uk&q=android%20webview%20proxy) - [первая ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy) - [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5719200/1568530).
На все потрачено 24 сек. А вы ждете ответа уже 7 часов.

```
private boolean setProxyHostField(HttpHost proxyServer) {
    // Getting network       
    Class networkClass = null;
    Object network = null;
    try { 
        networkClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.Network");
        Field networkField = networkClass.getDeclaredField("sNetwork");
        network = getFieldValueSafely(networkField, null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "error getting network");
        return false; 
    } 
    if (network == null) {
        Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "error getting network : null");
        return false; 
    } 
    Object requestQueue = null;
    try { 
        Field requestQueueField = networkClass
                .getDeclaredField("mRequestQueue");
        requestQueue = getFieldValueSafely(requestQueueField, network);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "error getting field value");
        return false; 
    } 
    if (requestQueue == null) {
        Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "Request queue is null");
        return false; 
    } 
    Field proxyHostField = null;
    try { 
        Class requestQueueClass = Class.forName("android.net.http.RequestQueue");
        proxyHostField = requestQueueClass
                .getDeclaredField("mProxyHost");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "error getting proxy host field");
        return false; 
    }        
    synchronized (synchronizer) { 
        boolean temp = proxyHostField.isAccessible(); 
        try { 
            proxyHostField.setAccessible(true); 
            proxyHostField.set(requestQueue, proxyServer); 
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
            Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "error setting proxy host"); 
        } finally { 
            proxyHostField.setAccessible(temp); 
        } 
    } 
    return true; 
} 

private Object getFieldValueSafely(Field field, Object classInstance) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    boolean oldAccessibleValue = field.isAccessible();
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object result = field.get(classInstance);
    field.setAccessible(oldAccessibleValue);
    return result;      
}
```